# Socket behaves as expected in VSCode, but closes after send in terminal

Tags: python, linux, sockets, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm working on a command line chat program and I'm running in to a strange issue where everything works as expected when running the client software in the VSCode debugger, but when I run the code in the terminal the socket closes after a single message. Server code works fine, the problem only seems to happen with the client. Terminal is my regular PopOS Gnome terminal, nothing fancy, no customization. Python version 3.8.6, PopOS 20.10, kernel is Linux 5.11.0-7612-generic, VSCode 1.56.1. VSCode has /usr/bin/python3 as the default interpreter, and this is a fresh install of PopOS in a VM under VMWare Workstation 16.

Running server in the terminal, here it is listening happily away:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33333         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3360/python3
```

I run the client, and the server registers it. Socket is comfortably established, waiting for me to send it a username:

Server text:

```
[WAITING FOR USERNAME] Awaiting username from ('127.0.0.1', 48280)
```

Netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33333         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3360/python3
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33333         127.0.0.1:48280         ESTABLISHED 3360/python3        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48280         127.0.0.1:33333         ESTABLISHED 4596/python3
```

I submit my username to the server, and it notes it:

```
[NEW USERNAME] Username 'Jim' belongs to ('127.0.0.1', 48280)
```

But what's this?!? Netstat has some bad news for me right away:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33333         127.0.0.1:48280         CLOSE_WAIT  3360/python3  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48280         127.0.0.1:33333         FIN_WAIT2   -
```

This only happens to the client, and only when running in the terminal. If I run the client in the VSCode debugger it'll gladly send text all day. Server text:

```
[WAITING FOR USERNAME] Awaiting username from ('127.0.0.1', 48328)
[NEW USERNAME] Username 'Jenny' belongs to ('127.0.0.1', 48328)
[NEW MESSAGE] Jenny: Heya
[NEW MESSAGE] Jenny: Hi there
[NEW MESSAGE] Jenny: How's it going
[NEW MESSAGE] Jenny: hey
```

Netstat too is reporting everything hunky-dory:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33333         127.0.0.1:48328         ESTABLISHED 3360/python3 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48328         127.0.0.1:33333         ESTABLISHED 4780/python3
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Either way, VSCode or terminal, it's the system's Python interpreter running the code so it should behave identically, right? But it doesn't. Any help is appreciated!

Here's the client code:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys

HEADER = 64
PORT = 33333
SERVER = '127.0.0.1'
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "#!@!DISCONNECT!@!#"

def send_msg(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.sendall(send_length)
    client.sendall(message)
    return True

def receive_messages(conn):
    while True:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length == '':
            continue
        msg_length = int(msg_length)
        msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
        print(msg)
        if msg[1:15] == "[DISCONNECTED]":
            return False
        if conn.fileno() <4:
            disconnected.set()
            return False

disconnected = threading.Event()

def got_disco():
    while True:
        if disconnected.is_set():
            client.shutdown(2) # Removes the socket's read/write ability
            client.close() # Closes the socket
            sys.exit()
        else:
            continue

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

# Receive login prompt
msg_length = client.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
if msg_length == '':
    msg_length = 0
msg_length = int(msg_length)
msg = client.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
print(msg)

# Input username and send it to server
client.sendall(input().encode(FORMAT))


#<<<>>>--> This is where the socket closes, right after the client.sendall() <--<<<>>>


# Creates a thread to listen for and print messages from the server
server_listen = threading.Thread(name="listen",target=receive_messages, args=(client,))
server_listen.start()

am_I_disco = threading.Thread(name='disco', target=got_disco)
am_I_disco.start()

while True:
    speak = input("\nSpeak: ")
    if speak == "q":
        send_msg(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
        print("\nDisconnecting. Goodbye!")
        disconnected.set()
    else:
        send_msg(speak)
        continue
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `input().encode(FORMAT)` contains when the socket closes?

Comment: `input().encode(FORMAT)` contains: b'Jenny'

Interestingly, the client works perfectly when I run it under Powershell in Windows Terminal using Python 3.9.5. I used pyenv to try running the client under Python 3.9.5 in PopOS and have the same problem. It doesn't occur at all with the server; no matter where it runs it can send to clients as much as it likes. So it's not a python version issue

Comment: Ach, I just figured it out. It was this part of the receive_messages() function:  

`if conn.fileno() <4:`  

I was trying to use the file descriptor as an easy way to check if the socket was up without having to try it and cause an exception; apparently something about the PopOS or Gnome Terminal handles that connection causes the file descriptor to be < 4. Only happens there though. Strange. –